# How to get dynamic id using HiddenField in Datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, hidden-field, hiddenfield

I am getting posts in datalist. I would like to show post id but i coundn't perfectly..

I would like to get post id with hidden field, any idea?

**I've tried on button click:**

```
protected void post_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HiddenField hiddenField = datalist1.Items[0].FindControl("hfield") as HiddenField;
    lbl_note.Text = Convert.ToString(hiddenField);
}
```

This is working but just for first hiddenfield because of Items[0], if you want to get second hiddenfiled than i can change Items[1].

But i would like to get those values to be automatically in datalist. (when i click the post's button)

I've tried foreach function but ***it get's last hidden field's value***. So, i miss something but i'm not sure.

```html
protected void post_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (DataListItem item in datalist1.Items)
   {
        var hidden_id = int.Parse(((HiddenField)item.FindControl("hfield")).Value); 
       lbl_note.Text = Convert.ToString(hidden_id);             
   }
}
```

**Datalist1:**

```html
<asp:DataList ID="datalist1" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>                
        <div>       
            <asp:LinkButton ID="post_picture" runat="server" OnClick="post_picture_Click"><img src="~/testing.png" alt=""></asp:LinkButton>     
            <h3><asp:LinkButton ID="post_title" runat="server" OnClick="post_title_Click"><%# Eval("post_title")%></asp:LinkButton></h3>
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="post_button" OnClick="post_button_Click" >GO >></asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfield" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("post_id")%>'  />
       </div>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

**UPDATED..**

Comment: what you want to display in `lbl_note.Text`

Comment: @un-lucky i have posts on the page, i would like to show post_id with hidden field.

Comment: So, if there are `n` hidden fields you need to show the id's of all the `n` hdnfields in that label right?

Comment: Please post **datalist1** mark up, so that we know how **button_Click** is triggered.

Comment: @un-lucky yes, that's right, but i would like to show post's id. if i can clicked third one than i need to see third post's id right?

Comment: @Win i updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to get DataListItem first, and then find hfield.

```
protected void post_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as LinkButton;
    var dataListItem = button.Parent as DataListItem;
    var hfield = dataListItem.FindControl("hfield") as HiddenField;
    lbl_note.Text = hfield.Value;
}
```

Comment: Yeap, i didn't think that.. Thank you @Win, it works.

Answer (score 1):

From the comment, you need to display all the id's of hidden fields in `lbl_note` so you have to use something like the following:

```
List<string> hdnIdList= new List<string>();
foreach (DataListItem item in datalist1.Items)
{
     hdnIdList.Add(((HiddenField)item.FindControl("hfield")).Value);                      
}
lbl_note.Text = String.Join("-",hdnIdList);
```

Let the id's are `001`, `002`and `003` the label will display the output as `001-002-003`

Comment: Well,i tried, there is no action.. I am not sure why.. Clicking on the post's button on the page but no error, no result.. @un-lucky